# How double-hashing works in leveldb?

Tags: leveldb, bloom-filter

When I read the implementation of bloom filter in leveldb, I found it use a trick to apply double-hashing.

[source](https://github.com/google/leveldb/blob/v1.20/util/bloom.cc#L54)

```
      // Use double-hashing to generate a sequence of hash values.
      // See analysis in [Kirsch,Mitzenmacher 2006].
      uint32_t h = BloomHash(keys[i]);
      const uint32_t delta = (h >> 17) | (h << 15);  // Rotate right 17 bits
      for (size_t j = 0; j < k_; j++) {
        const uint32_t bitpos = h % bits;
        array[bitpos/8] |= (1 << (bitpos % 8));
        h += delta;
      }
```

There is no second hash function, but just rotate 17 bits.

I'm wondering how the 17 chosen?
And, if I want to use the same trick to a uint64_t, how many bits should I rotate?